# Create 2 NuGet packages from 1 .net standard library

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have created a .net standard class library holding a class and 2 cmdlets.
I want to package it as a nuget package for .net projects to reference and one nuget package for powershell scripts.

The class library itself is made of with the new sdk style .csproj format.

How can I create within one project (the class library) 2 nuget packages, also using the nuget msbuild syntax (using property groups) ?

(I tried it, but I could only create one nuget package with the class library project.
I also tried to create 2 new class library projects having a project reference to the class library holding the c# code, but I don't know how to include the build output of the class library as content)

Comment: Use .nuspec files.

Comment: Why would you do it this way? Create 3 class libraries, put your class in 1 and inherit in the other two.  Check the checkbox in your favorite IDE to create the nuget package and don't confuse whoever is going to inherit your solution.

Comment: Microsoft recommends the use of properties inside the sdk style project, so nuspec files are a no-go